# Visa for dual Australian citizen child to visit Australia

Tags: australia, dual-nationality, children, australian-citizens

I would like to visit Australia with my daughter. I am not an Australian citizen, but my daughter is a dual citizen, Australian and Ecuadorian. However, she has never had an Australian passport. Her father lives in Australia. Last time we went to Australia she was not an Australian citizen yet so she was included in my visa. Can I do the same this time? Or what kind of visa does she need?

Comment: Is your daughter likely to travel to Australia again in the next few years? If so, it's probably better to get her an Australian passport - no visa required. She might also find other international travel on an Australian passport easier.

Comment: If you properly fill the visa form, they should deny the visa on grounds that an Australian citizen **cannot get** an Australian visa.

Comment: @o.m. many countries have such a rule.  Do you know for sure that Australia does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your daughter needs to get an Australian passport.  Under [subsection 29(1) of the *Migration Act 1959*](https://www.legislation.gov.au/Details/C2019C00091/Html/Volume_1#_Toc2334479), the government only has the legal authority to issue visas to non-citizens.

Australian citizens (including dual nationals) should use their Australian passport to enter or depart Australia.  While it is theoretically possible for a dual national to enter Australia with a foreign passport with another proof of Australian citizenship once they arrive in Australia, practically airlines will deny boarding to Australian citizens who do not check in with an Australian passport, as they will fail the electronic immigration status check.

The Department's [advice to dual nationals](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/entering-and-leaving-australia/traveling-as-a-dual-citizen) is as follows (emphasis added):

> **Australian citizens entering and leaving Australia**
>
> Australian citizens should use their Australian passport to enter and leave Australia.
>
> The Australian Border Force has more information on [crossing the border](https://www.abf.gov.au/entering-and-leaving-australia/crossing-the-border/at-the-border).
>
> If you have a passport from another country, you can use that after you leave Australia.
>
> A passport is the best way to show that you are an Australian citizen. You might still be able to enter Australia if you are an Australian citizen without an Australian passport, but it will be more difficult. **The airline might also stop you from boarding a plane to Australia.**

Comment: If she has never had an Australian passport, how will Australia know that she's an Australian citizen?

Comment: @phoog: Presumably they know her _father_ is one of their citizens, and generally a birth certificate will document that she's her father's daughter. The father will probably need to cooperate with some kind of procedure for registering the birth of Australians abroad.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I find it unlikely that this information would lead to a denial of boarding after a visa is issued.  It would either cause the visa to be denied or boarding would be permitted.  Also, k2moo4, "should" is not "must."  The government's text reads more like advice than a legal requirement.

Comment: The emphasis here is somewhat misleading. The airline isn't interested in citizenship. They care only that the passenger has appropriate documentation. A valid passport with a valid visa will be enough for them, and nothing on the Australian Immigration page linked to prohibits an Australian with a second citizenship from using that to enter Australia.

Comment: @phoog: Sorry, I misunderstood. I somehow thought your point was, "how can she convince Australia they should give her a passport?"

Comment: @HenningMakholm indeed, my first comment was perhaps too terse.  It was a response to "practically airlines will deny boarding to Australian citizens who do not check in with an Australian passport, as they will fail the electronic immigration status check."  Even for someone who *does* have an Australian passport, for that to happen, the foreign passport they use to check in would have to be matched to the Australian passport record or another record.  I have no idea how likely Australia's systems are to do that, but it seems far less likely for someone who never had a passport.

Comment: @phoog Australia does link passports of dual-nationals when they depart Australia, see section 3 of the [APP manual](https://www.abf.gov.au/help-and-support-subsite/files/advance-passenger-processing.pdf) for details. They won't be able to do that those who don't have an Australian passport though.